# A C# Setup Project that will copy an additional file if it exists in the SOURCE folder

Tags: c#, installation

I've created a setup project which works just fine. However, I'd like to have the ability where if I were to place a config.ini file inside the SOURCE directory of the setup.exe file, this will be copied to the installation directory during installation.

So if there is no config.ini file in the setup folder, the installer would run as normal. But if there is one, this would be copied over to the installation directory on the client machine.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so... how?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you add your custom action in the setup project.....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. It might be my limited knowledge/understanding, but when I tried to do this by adding a Custom Action, it only seems to allow me to select "File System on Target Machine" as opposed to from the Source Directory.

Comment: In Custom Action Commit method, you can either read the file from source location, which could be location of web or some shared location then you can write C# code to copy\download file from source location to local location in target machine.....Still want some code sample then give me some time I ll post answer

Comment: Once again, thank you for your speedy reply. My Setup,exe exists in a network folder. From a client, I can run the setup and install. However, I'd like to be able to simply add a config.ini file this to the network folder, so when I run setup from the client, it copies this ini file over during installation if it exists.

Comment: I've been reading a bit on the Custom Actions, but not sure I fully understand. Would I be right in thinking I need to create a new DLL with the custom action for checking if the config.ini files exists and performing the copy etc, and then add this DLL to my Setup Project as a Custom Action?